# Determine $P(B_{s} > 0, B_{t} > 0)$ where $s < t$

Tags: real-analysis, probability, probability-theory, measure-theory, brownian-motion

Let **B** be a brownian motion, and set $t < s$. Determine $P(B_{s} > 0, B_{t} > 0)$.

Seeing as though this is a brownian motion I assume we have to use the increments, so:

$P(B_{s} > 0, B_{t} > 0)=P(B_{s}-B_{0}>0, B_{t}-B_{s}>-B_{s})$

Now obviously the $-B_{s}$ in $B_{t}-B_{s}>-B_{s}$ the only thing bugging me... any suggestions?

Comment: Use conditional probabilities to arrive at $$P(B_t - B_s>B_0 -B_s| B_s>0)\cdot P(B_s>0)$$ then use Gaussian RV property of increments.

Comment: Look at this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2776307/find-pbs0-bt0-where-bs-is-brownian-motion-st)